# How to set default catalog with linked server in Mssql

Tags: sql-server, odbc, linked-server

Formerly, I had two databases in one physical server. ('People' and 'Work' Database)
So I used the below query when 'People'  database information need at 'Work' database.

```
select * from People.dbo.information
```

But, It occurred to me something that one physical databases have to be seperatored with two physical server. 
Therefore I made linked server connection at 'People' database server for refering Information at 'Work' database same as before name and Then I seted dafualt catalog the 'People' in linked server.

Although I already seted default catalog, I have to enter database's name and can't skip the name.

Phycal Databases was seperatored but I want to use previous query using linked server.

Example)
If i made linked server as called 'Peoplo', I have to use below query.

```
select * from People.People.dbo.information
--select * from [linked name].[db name].[dbo].[table Name]
```

I want to use below query.

```
select * from People.dbo.information
    --select * from [linked name].[dbo].[table Name]
    --Then, linked name is seted with default catalog as 'People'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the "default database" for the login on the linked server, you can use this (2 dots, skipping default catalog)

```
select * from People..dbo.information
```

Note that however you do it, linked servers can have performance issues when joining between servers.

Also note, the data has no referential integrity *at all*. The databases will not be synchromised or coherent in case of any downtime or restores etc

Comment: thank you for reply. So I wonder that can use without 2 dots. In other words it will use 'select * from People.dbo.information' instead 'select * from People..dbo.information'.

Can not you do it in any way?

Comment: `People..dbo.information` is Linked server "People", default remote database. People. `People.dbo.information` is local database People. You have to use 2 dots

Comment: thanks! umm..So I have to change my program code and sql procedure two dots. Because at that time, that was used in one physical server.. But that is separated now..

Thank you again one.